# How to use libSVM for one-class SVM problems?

Tags: svm, libsvm

I plan to use libSVM for a one-class svm problem, but I'm not sure about the meaning of `nu` in `svm_parameter`.

Does it mean the probability that a test point lies *outside* of a set S (estimated from the training data) equals `nu`?

Comment: Related to: [SVM with only one type of label](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/41324/930).

Comment: How did you set the label of training data and test data

Comment: @Mark.M, What's the meaning of the labels vector in the case of One Class SVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A Tutorial on $\nu$-Support Vector Machines](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/nusvmtutorial.pdf) [PDF]
(Section 6, proposition 1)
It's not exactly a probability.
In the context of soft-margin SVM, we introduce slack variables in the margin and minimize its sum, and:

- "(i) $\nu$ is an upper bound on the fraction of margin errors (and hence
  also on the fraction of training errors).
- (ii) $\nu$ is a lower bound on the fraction of Support Vectors."

Comment: my training data consists of the instances from the class I want to identify, and I know most real-world data will NOT fall into that class. Should I set the value of nu to be smaller (e.g., less than 0.5?)

Comment: Well, that's a good question. What I didn't understand is how the information of the "real-world data" could change the way you set the "nu" parameter. 
As I see it, you need to expect that your training will generalize and, in that sense, the parameter nu is related to how many outliers are going to be permitted (or, it's a upper bound in the fraction of training points outside the estimated region). Nevertheless, a small "nu" indicates a bigger region to be estimated. 
(http://www.springerlink.com/content/978-3-540-34628-9/#section=496010&page=3&locus=9)
What you say may work in this sense.